# In Android WebViews, how to run javascript on different threads?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have two WebViews `wv1` and `wv2` and let's say `wv1` executes a javascript code `jsCode1` and `wv2` executes another javascript code `jsCode2`, which is something like:

```
wv1.evaluateJavascript(jsCode1, null);
wv2.evaluateJavascript(jsCode2, null);
```

Initially I guess `jsCode1` and `jsCode2` will be executed on different threads because I thought different WebView instances will create their own threads to execute JavaScript code.

But it turns out I was wrong because I find out `jsCode1` and `jsCode2` are running on the same thread.

So does it mean the Android system assigns only one thread for all the JavaScript to run? If not, how can I run javascript in multiple threads using WebViews?